# How to prevent a RecyclerView item from gravitating to it's original position after dropping it over a target

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

Iet's assume an app that a RecyclerView with an associated ItemTouchHelper has been implemented and the following basic operation has occurred:

1. Drag invoked on a RecyclerView item and it's hovering over another "Target" item.
2. The drag item is released before an onMove callback is invoked.
3. The clearView callback is invoked where I was thinking the app would then complete a merge of the two items.
4. What I observe is that the drag item moseys back to it's pre-drop position.

I'd like to prevent the drag item from naturally gravitating back to it's original position before clearView gets a chance to do it's magic since having the drag item move back and then disappear is not desired.

What's the best way to implement this to prevent the drag item from moseying back to it's last position ahead of the merge operation?

Comment: I hadn't previously noticed that onSelectedChanged gets called with the actionState value passed in with ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE when the drag item is released pretty quickly, much quicker than clearView being called.  This gets rid of the moseying back part, but still leaves a significant time lag where the item, once hidden, leaves a big hole where it used to be until the drag item is reported as removed.

Comment: Previously, I had noticed an issue with calling notifyItemMoved from within clearView if the RecyclerView was scrolling, so I'm not confident I can reliably call any of the reporting methods like notifyItemMoved or notifyItemRemoved from onSelectedChanged  either.  Any advice out there on this detail, or should I start a new question?